# Can you use iPod objects through iTunes COM SDK?

Tags: com, ipod, itunes-sdk

I am currently trying to use the tracks located on an iPod (not synchronized with the computer I use), to create a specific playlist.

Is it possible to have a playlist/source that represents a non-synchronized iPod?
I have heard that reading music from an iPod without synchronizing it is possible, but have not experienced it. If so, it would probably be represented within iTunes as a playlist. Does anyone know?

The second question would be: is there a way to control it through COM? (I use Python, but am used to transform from other languages)

After a small research, I ended up on [this](http://www.aqua-soft.org/forum/topic/31450-adding-tracks-to-ipod-with-windows-com-sdk-c/), but that's all, and I do not know this language...

> ♪ Help, I need somebody,
>
> Help, not just anybody,
>
> Help, you know I need someone, help. ♪

Anyone?

Thanks